# My primary monitor is always showing a terminal

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, multiple-monitors, lightdm, tty

I have 2 monitors plus my screen laptop. I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.4 and was having some issues with the display manager I tried gdm3, lightdm and then sddm.

Now, I went back to lightdm because it's the one with fewest bugs for me. My 2 monitors are good and detected, but my laptop screen is always showing a command line (tty)  and I can only access it when I type ctrl + alt + F2. Any help guys ? My laptop monitor is not even detected in Displays.

Answer (score 0):

This problem took me hours. But I couldn't find a solution except reinstalling nvidia. Here's what I've done:
First, To purge everything related to nvidia. I run this command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
```

Then reinstall ubuntu-desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
echo 'nouveau' | sudo tee -a /etc/modules
```

After that I rebooted, then I noticed I no longer have the problem. But the gpu driver used was `nouveau`. So I needed to install the nvidia again:

So go to **Software & Updates** > **Additional Drivers**,  then choose the nvidia driver you want to install (in my case I chose nvidia-driver-450-server).